# HTML5 placeholder remains in Tokenfield after tokens created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tokenize

I am using [Bootstrap Tokenfield](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/) on an input field.

The field has a placeholder attribute "Username".

```
<input id="email-notifications" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
```

When I start typing in the field (in Chrome 31), the placeholder goes away as expected.  However, once the tokenfield validates an email address and it's made into a token, the placeholder text reappears.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/FKYaj/1/) of the whole setup

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove placeholder after addition of token and set it back after deletion and if there is no more tokens. Please see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3q5m/).

All that I have done is added this inside `afterCreateToken` handler

```
$('#email-notifications-tokenfield').attr('placeholder', '');
```

and this inside `removeToken`

```
if(!$('#email-notifications').tokenfield('getTokens').length)
   $('#email-notifications-tokenfield').attr('placeholder', 'Username');
```

Note that I set and remove placeholder from `#email-notifications-tokenfield` field.